# how to add text inbetween pre tags

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code in a switch:

```
case 'php':
           $(TextArea).insertRoundTag('pre', htmlOpts, {lang:'php', line:'1'});
           break;
```

The result is that when it is executed, in a textarea appears:

```
<pre lang="php" line="1"></pre>
```

Now people can paste code between the **pre** tags
How can i add the text "code here" between the **pre** tags and is blue (selected)?

```
<pre lang="php" line="1">code here</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert the "code here" text, just grab the value from the textarea and insert it. The replacement in the following code only assumes some HTML element within the textarea, i.e. not just e.g. the "pre" tags:

```
var codeText = "code here";
var oldVal = $(TextArea).val();
$(TextArea).val(oldVal.replace("></", ">" + codeText  + "</"));
```

To select the "code here" text:

```
$(TextArea).focus();
var position = $(TextArea).val().indexOf(codeText);
document.getElementById(TextArea).setSelectionRange(position , position + codeText.length);
```

Hope this helps!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ttbjenn2/1/

Comment: This works really good but there is a little problem: I have several buttons and when pressing them there comes something like pre lang="php" line="1", and pre lang="css" line="1' and so one...choosing the **js** button deletes the other pre's in the textarea

Comment: Sounds like a problem with insertRoundTag, you might want to create a new question about it. :)